# nginx serving default page instead of serving a express API via reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have been following this [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-20-04) tutorial.

I have a simple express server setup and running at port 3333:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3333;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World!\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

pm2 shows the process as online and running, nothing is shown in the logs. However, when I access the site in the web browser I get the default nginx server page: https://image-parser.shooshte.com/ . I was expecting to get the default API response here. I am also unable to ping the server using postman.

This is my nginx `/etc/nginx/sites-available/image-parser` config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/image-parser/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name image-parser www.image-parser.shooshte.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:3333;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/image-parser.shooshte.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/image-parser.shooshte.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a symlink from `/nginx/etc/sites-enabled/image-parser` to `/nginx/etc/sites-available/image-parser`? Check `nginx -T` command output to see the actual nginx config.

Comment: @IvanShatsky sry, new to nginx so don't know if I understand the question correctly. I see this under virtual hosts config after running `nignx -T` `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` It then lists a lot of config files, including the one from the question as the last one.

Comment: actually, it lists `default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` first, then `/etc/nginx/sites-available/image-parser`

Comment: 1. You don't specify `image-parser.shooshte.com` as a server name, you probably want `server_name image-parser.shooshte.com www.image-parser.shooshte.com;` instead of `server_name image-parser www.image-parser.shooshte.com;`. 2. Why do you specify an HTTPS scheme in the `proxy_pass https://localhost:3333;` directive? Your backend is using a plain HTTP protocol. 3. Why do you put those `proxy_http_version 1.1;`, `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;`, `proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';` and `proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;` lines?

Comment: These are required to [proxy a WebSocket connection](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) only and can break a regular HTTP connection. You do not define any caching mechanism to use `proxy_cache_bypass`, and if you want to proxy both WebSocket and HTTP connections, you should use the second recipe (that one with the `map` block) from the aforementioned article.